# How to get value entered in search box In Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to get value entered in search box In Datatables.
Is there a way to get value entered in search box in Data Tables?

Comment: Is [this](http://datatables.net/reference/option/searching) what you are asking about? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your response .I am using the search feature and I want to get the exact text entered in the search box of data table,I have a requirement to sent a server side request when the text in search box is cleared.So I am looking for a way to get the entered text and check if the length is zero and send server side request . I hope I am clear.

Comment: I think you might want to add `jQuery` to your list of tags to attract a bigger crowd.

Comment: #1 result in Google for 'datatables pull contents of search box'. Perfection!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you just want to check the value when a search is performed [dataTables **1.10.x**] :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on('search.dt', function() {
    var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
    console.log(value); // <-- the value
});
```

if you want to check the value before the search, and be able to cancel the search, you must unbind the default searchbox event and create your own, like this - search only when the user has entered more than 3 characters :

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length>3) {
        table.search(value).draw();
    } 
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pb0632c3/**

To reset the search / filter completely, like if the user has deleted the search term :

```
if (value.length==0) table.search('').draw();
```

Comment: `table.column().search(value).draw();` shouldn't be `table.search(value).draw();`?

Comment: @MárcioSouzaJúnior, you are right. Thank you! Have changed text and fiddle. Strange I'd used `column()` in the example.

Comment: @davidkonrad try `dataTable.search()`. I'm not sure if it's documented

Comment: How to get searched value on the server-side (PHP) in case of column search ?

Comment: @DavidG you must send it to the server by yourself. Something like `$.post({ url: 'server.php', data: { search: table.search() }})` you could also just read the dataTables cookie, if you set `stateSave: true` ...

Answer (score 29):

Yes, there is. You call the search method without an argument to get the search term

`var query = dataTable.search()`

https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

> Get the currently applied global search. If there is more than one
> table in the API's context, the search term of the first table will be
> returned. Use table() if you require the search term of a different
> table in the API's context.

Comment: thanks, the other answers are so complicated :) works great

Comment: @danday74, yes, agree, and I have recommended that in other ansers as well. But if you look at the question, OP want the content of the search box. `.search()` just gives you the current search term, if any, and that could be a programmatically or plugin-based search, not just the content of the search box.

Comment: @davidkonrad,  "How to get the value entered....". Read the title of the question. Or maybe my English is just extremely terrible

Comment: @peterchaula, gee, that was old :) I refer to the comment below OP's question: "*,I have a requirement to sent a server side request **when the text in search box is cleared**.So I am looking for a way to get the entered text and check if the length is zero and send server side request*". Happy new year!

Comment: @davidkonrad yeah, that was old. Happy new year!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [dataTable api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

```
    var table = $('.datatable').DataTable();


     $('.datatable').on('search.dt', function (e, settings) {
       table.search( this.value ).draw();
    })

    //or custom input
    // #myInput is a <input type="text" id="myInput"> element
    $('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
        table.search( this.value ).draw();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this works for all datatable version
what we are doing here is  tracking the search input field and then getting its value only
no need to use datatable api using this method

```
$('input[type="search"]').on( 'keyup', function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to detect the key press and then draw the DataTablee.

```js
$('#search').on('keyup change', function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.api().search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I dont think this will work, in dt the input type search is not created with an id of search

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in Javascript under Datatable code
;

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

If still not working,
Add none display span element next to the input you want to search

```
 <td>
      <input class="form-control" value="{{Value}}">
      <span style="display:none"> {{Value}} </span>>
    </td>
```

Replace value and span inner text must be the same! That is.