# Keep search value between tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny App similar to this one : http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html

I would like to keep the value entered in the Search bar when one switches tab. How can this be achieved? I assume I have to access to a value in library(shiny).

[image]

Comment: How about create textInput in UI, then use input$myFilter inside DT:data.table, and hide Search option in DT.

Comment: I just started to use Shiny, what do you mean by hiding search option in DT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2 options, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590778) we can extract the text from the GlobalSearch. I am not proficient in jQuery to advise any further.

Or we can use custom search using `inputText` that can be used to subset all the tables.

Insert this line to **ui.R**:

```
textInput("myFilter", "myFilter", "good")
```

Then subset your DT tables in **server.R**, as an example change **output$mytable1** to below. This will search every column for matching input text (it can get slow so you might need to select some of the columns to search):

```
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    diamonds[
      apply(diamonds, 1, function(i) any(grepl(input$myFilter, as.character(i),
                                               ignore.case = TRUE))), ]
  })
```

Do the same change for other DT table outputs using the same `input$myFilter`.

Regarding hiding search box, see `dom` options of DT, an
example from [rstudio DT manual](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html):

```
# only display the table, and nothing else
datatable(head(iris), options = list(dom = 't'))
```

Comment: Thank you, the second solution works for me even though the first solution seems better and cleaner. When I use `, options = list(dom = 't')` the pages are disabled and only the first page is shown, any workaround?