# Datatable searching is not working

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using Datatable in my project for robust searching and many more
advantages of datatable but when i need a value of search box the searching of datatable is not working. Actually i need searching as well as value of search box for deleting the data but when i apply a code of getting the value of search box the searching is not working in datable.

Below is my code.

```
<html>
    <title>Example 1 - apply dataTable()</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">


        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


  </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>varun</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>22</td>
            <td>nitin</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script code:

```
<script>
    $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

//getting the value of search box
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length>3) {
        alert(value);
        table.search(value).draw();
    } else {     
        //optional, reset the search if the phrase 
        //is less then 3 characters long
        table.search('').draw();
    }        
});

 </script>
```

Please Help me,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you have unbind.keyUp function there? I mean, why unbind?

Comment: Actually i dont have much knowledge about jquery i have found this code from below stack link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590778/how-to-get-value-entered-in-search-box-in-datatables and thank you so much for your valuable comment it save my day.

Answer (score 1):

You were calling DataTable 2 times in the code. I've updated and prepared a fiddle for it.

```js
var table=$('#example').DataTable();

//getting the value of search box
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length>3) {
        alert(value);
        table.search(value).draw();
    } else {     
        //optional, reset the search if the phrase 
        //is less then 3 characters long
        table.search('').draw();
    }        
});
```

```html
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td> 4</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.9</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.7</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td>1.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>125.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td>312.8</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>419.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>522.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td>420</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td>420.1</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>413</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td>8.5</td>
            <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td>3.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mqavj0a/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the woring code

```html
<html>
<title>Example 1 - apply dataTable()</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>varun</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>nitin</td>
       </tr>

     </tbody>
   </table>

 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
  $('#example').DataTable();
} );
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right direction but where is the rest of the code ? Where is poster's unbind function?