# Read value from search request Datatable?

Tags: datatables

I am trying to read value from search box of Datatable.
This is request payload:

```
[Object: null prototype] {


draw: '8',
  'columns[0][data]': '_id',
  'columns[0][name]': '',
  'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[0][orderable]': 'true',
  ...
  start: '0',
  length: '50',
  'search[value]': 'id3dsd3dsdddsddsd',
  'search[regex]': 'false'
}
```

I want to get value from search[value]. I get this error after using this code:

```
req.body.search.value
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

Anyone can help me!

Comment: Can you provide the code you are running as part of a [mre]?

Comment: Where/how are you trying to read that data? The JSON looks like it's part of the server-side request sent from the DataTables to the server. So are you trying to intercept this in the browser? Or process it on the server? Or are you actually doing something completely different?

Comment: Or maybe all you need is something like this? [How to get value entered in search box In Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26590778/12567365)

Comment: This is server-side request sent from the DataTables to the server. It is a object but req.body.search.value is undefined. I don't know why? While req.body.length return 50.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would solve your problem.

```
let search_str = req.body['search[value]'];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).